# clang-format -style no respond

Tags: cmd, clang, clang-format

I want to change indent width of clang-format for my vs-code. When I type         `$ clang-format -style="{IndentWidth: 4}"`   in cmd in windows, the cmd  responded nothing and this command kept running.

```
user@win10-asus MINGW64 /c/Program Files (x86)/LLVM/bin
$ clang-format -style="{IndentWidth: 4}"
```

Should I type some letters ?

Answer (score 0):

From the clang-format documentation:

> If no arguments are specified, it formats the code from standard input
>   and writes the result to the standard output.

You need to specify one ore more filenames on the command line that are then processed by `clang-format`. Otherwise the tool waits for input.

Comment: How many inputs should I write?  should I write all settings listed in the document? That would be terrible.

Comment: The inputs are not your settings, but the file(s) you want formatted.